# Firefox extension that warns me when I "like" a Facebook post which is not "friends-only"

Tags: gratis, firefox, facebook

I want a Firefox extension that warns me every time I try to "like" a post which is not "friends-only".

## Context

In Facebook, people can make their posts:

- Public
- Visible to friends-of-friends
- Visible to friends-only
- Private (only the poster can see)

Now, let's say I want to "like" posts about politics, but I would rather avoid my political preferences to be seen by anyone but my friends. That's why I decided to **only like posts that are "friends-only"**:

[image: Shared with friends]

While "public" is easy to spot (globe icon), "friends-of-friends" has the same grey icon [image: friends icon] as seen in the screenshot above, so before liking anything I have to hover the icon to check, which is a pain.

## Details

- Must be free
- Firefox extension or Greasemonkey/etc script or anything that works for Firefox
- Just showing friends-of-friends-visible posts with a different icon (not [image: friends icon]) is acceptable too